# Error at npm start after I am trying install SVGR in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

There is a requirement to handle SVG in React and I am installing svgr/webpack to take it. However I occur some error. In log file

[image]

And also run audit fix, but feedback about:
[image]

It's really hard to understand for me, anyone can tell me how to solve?

Comment: Did you use `npm install @svgr/webpack --save-dev` command for install the package and follow the steps in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack

Comment: It looks like you have a general issue in your startup script but the log doesn't really tell why. My advice would be to roll back your changes and do one change after another. Installing a package and running an npm audit fix blindly will lead to issues. Fix you start up script, install the new package, verify your project is running and then run an `npm audit`. `npm audit fix` will patch every issue which it knows to be solved by an version increment (normally patch version). But this can introduce misbehaviour

Comment: Also the `Prototype Pollution` issue tells you what todo. To solve the vulnerability you need to manually increment the version of the package `react-scripts`